# Is it normal to reply Yes/No to an "A or B" question?

Tags: questions, coordination

Below is from Assimil French:

> "Voulez-vous aller tout de suite à votre hôtel ou voulez-vous passer au bureau d'abord ? "
>
> "Non, je veux déposer mes affaires d'abord."

So facing an "A or B" question, the guy replied *No*, to reject "B" and then continue to take "A". Is it normal in French? I always thought one can't anwer "yes/no" to a choice question as this might be confusing.

Comment: Then continue to take **"A"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complément de réponse

Même pour une alternative courte, il n'est pas correct de répondre « non » ; la seule possibilité de donner une réponse courte et cohérente à une question proposant deux alternatives est de répondre « Ni l'un ni l'autre. » ou encore « Aucun des deux. ».

Il faut cependant accorder ces deux formes lorsqu'il s'agit, non d'actions formulées au moyen de verbes, mais de noms (ou plus généralement de formes nominales).

- (*même genre*) Voulez-vous la pièce rouge ou la jaune? **Ni l'une ni l'autre.**
  *autre possibilité* : **Aucune des deux.**
- (*même genre*) Prennent-ils le train ou l'avion? **Ni l'un ni l'autre.**
  *autre possibilité* : **Aucun des deux.**
- (*genres mixte*) Ont-ils une villa ou un appartement? **Ni l'un ni l'autre.**
  *autre possibilité* : **Aucun des deux.**
  Dans ce cas c'est le masculin qui l'emporte.

Answer (score 4):

With a short alternative, *non* would only be used to (lazily<sup>1</sup>) reject both questions (i. e. none of the above), e.g.:

> Tu veux de la viande ou (tu veux) du poisson ?
>
> Non, je veux rien !

In your example, *non* is only replying to the second question which is long enough to overshadow the first one.

Despite being incorrect as far as the logic is concerned, it is common for people to select the question which is given a yes/no answer, essentially the last one<sup>2</sup>, when more than one is present. There is anyway no ambiguity left because the *non* is clarified by providing details: that *non* hides a *oui*: the person wants to go to the hotel first to drop their luggage.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Lazily because *ni l'un, ni l'autre* and variants are better, as user168676 detailed in his reply.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>This is a little similar to the *proximity agreement* which used to exist until the 18th century.</sub>

Comment: While I agree with the explanation of why they did that, I would not say it myself. It sounds a lot more natural to me to answer something like « Je voudrais déposer mes affaires d’abord ».